# Copy Range to Another Worksheet Using Input Box to Choose Range

Tags: vba, variables, range, copy-paste, inputbox

I am writing a VBA macro where I have an InputBox come up, the user will select a range which will be a full column, and then the macro will paste that range in a particular place on another worksheet.  I have been trying to make this code work, but I keep getting different errors depending on what I try to fix, so I was wondering if someone could help me out.  I have pasted the relevant parts of the code:

```
Sub Create_CONV_Files()

Dim NewCode As Range
Set NewCode = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select the column with the code numbers", Title:="New Event Selector", Type:=8)

Dim RawData As Worksheet
Set RawData = ActiveSheet

Dim OffSht As Worksheet
Set OffSht = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
OffSht.Name = "offset.sac"

Worksheets(RawData).Range(NewCode).Copy _
  Destination:=OffSht.Range("A:A")

End Sub
```

I have tried making the input a string instead, but I am also getting errors there and am not sure how to fix that.  I was hoping to use roughly the method I have outlined as my full code has multiple destination sheets and ranges.

Thank you very much for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once you have set a `Range` object it brings with it its worksheet property so there's no need to qualify its worksheet

```
Sub Create_CONV_Files()

    Dim NewCode As Range
    Set NewCode = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select the column with the code numbers", title:="New Event Selector", Type:=8)

    Dim OffSht As Worksheet
    Set OffSht = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.count))
    OffSht.Name = "offset.sac"

    NewCode.Copy _
    Destination:=OffSht.Range("A1")

End Sub
```

Comment: You're a genius! That worked perfectly!  Thank you so much!!  Can I ask about how you changed my Range A:A to A1?  I changed my ranges to match yours, but I'm wondering if that was a best practices type change or if the Destination Range only takes the first cell of the range.